# How to correctly shift the wipers of MCP4331 per SPI?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, spi, microchip, digital-potentiometer

I am using an STM32 F401RE to control a Quad 7-bit digital potentiometer MCP 4331 using SPI Mode 0,0 protocol. You can find the datasheet [Here](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/22242A.pdf). I can see that the microcontroller sends the correct clock and byte to shift the wiper (in this case Wiper 1) and the digipot actually replies per MISO "1111111" which means the command is correct. You can find the image of the osci below. As default, the potentiometer begins at midscale and when I make the resistance measurements with the multimeter, the wiper remains in the sam position no matter how many times I try to increment it.

The wiring of SCK, MISO, MOSI, CS and RESET are correct. The supply voltage is of 3.3V and both CS and RESET have a pull-down resistor. Am I perhaps missing something?[image]

Comment: How did you measure the resistance? Between what pins? Did you try them all? Do you also need to update the wiper memory of the chip?

Comment: Thanks for replying Andy. I measured from terminal A-W and B-W. I also interconnected two terminals (BW) and measured on A...just like a normal potentiometer but it's the same value I did this for one pot only. As far as I understood you send the command and the wiper should move, then the CS must have a high state afterwards

Comment: The valid command is to increment or decrement one bit. Maybe you need to send several consecutive commands so you can see the effect easier?

Comment: Actually the increments run within a loop. It should actually increment to the maximum value

Answer (score 0):

You have 7 clock pulses for each byte.

The chip works with 8-bit bytes.

Also as reset and chip select are active low, generally you would pull them up. Reset must be high, and CS controlled with MCU.

Comment: The correct 16-bit or 8-bit clocking format is shown in the datasheet in Figures 6-2, 6-3, 6-4, and 6.5.